# Update column in table A based off columns in table B which have to meet a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have 2 tables to model a vacation request and the approvers who will approve the request. A request can have several approvers.

When an approver approves, the approver row has its approved_at column set to the current date.

The request table also has an approved_at column. This is set when ALL the approvers have approved and it is set to the most recent approver's approved_at date.

I need to backfill the requests table's approved at column with the most recent approver's approved_at time but only if all the approvers have approved.

I have solved it using a CTE with window functions but I'm wondering what other ways are there to solve this? I'd prefer a solution compliant with postgres.

Here's my solution

```sql
create table reqs (
  id serial primary key,
  approved_at date
);

create table req_approvers (
  id serial primary key,
  req_id int,
  approved_at date
);

insert into reqs (id) values (1),(2),(3);

insert into req_approvers (req_id, approved_at)
values
(1, '2022-01-01'),
(1, '2021-01-01'),
(1, NULL),
(1, '2020-01-01'),
(2, '1999-01-01'),
(2, '1979-01-01');

-- View the data by joining the two tables on the req_id 

select 
reqs.id as req_id, 
reqs.approved_at as req_approved_at, 
req_approvers.id as req_apvr_id,
req_approvers.req_id as req_apvr_req_id,
req_approvers.approved_at as req_apvr_approved_at
from reqs
left outer join req_approvers on req_approvers.req_id = reqs.id;


/*
 req_id | req_approved_at | req_apvr_id | req_apvr_req_id | req_apvr_approved_at
--------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------
      1 |                 |           1 |               1 | 2022-01-01
      1 |                 |           2 |               1 | 2021-01-01
      1 |                 |           3 |               1 |
      1 |                 |           4 |               1 | 2020-01-01
      2 |                 |           5 |               2 | 1999-01-01
      2 |                 |           6 |               2 | 1979-01-01
      3 |                 |             |                 |
*/

-- From the above only req 2 has been fully approved so only its approved_at column should be set to the date 1999-01-01


WITH req_approval_stats AS (
    SELECT
            DISTINCT reqs.id
            -- get the most recent approvers approval date
            ,MAX (req_approvers.approved_at) OVER (
                PARTITION BY reqs.id
            ) AS approved_at
            -- get the total number of approvers for this request
            ,COUNT (req_approvers.id) OVER (
                PARTITION BY reqs.id
            ) AS total_approvers
            -- get the total number of approvers who have approved for this request
            ,COUNT (req_approvers.approved_at) OVER (
                PARTITION BY reqs.id
            ) AS total_approved
        FROM
            reqs INNER JOIN req_approvers
                ON reqs.id = req_approvers.req_id
) UPDATE
        reqs
    SET
        approved_at = (
            SELECT
                    req_approval_stats.approved_at
                FROM
                    req_approval_stats
                WHERE
                    req_approval_stats.total_approvers = req_approval_stats.total_approved
                    AND req_approval_stats.id = reqs.id LIMIT 1
        )


-- view the data again and its correct 
 
/*
 req_id | req_approved_at | req_apvr_id | req_apvr_req_id | req_apvr_approved_at
--------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------
      1 |                 |           1 |               1 | 2022-01-01
      1 |                 |           2 |               1 | 2021-01-01
      1 |                 |           3 |               1 |
      1 |                 |           4 |               1 | 2020-01-01
      2 | 1999-01-01      |           5 |               2 | 1999-01-01
      2 | 1999-01-01      |           6 |               2 | 1979-01-01
      3 |                 |             |                 |
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can appropriate approved date using `distinct on` sorting on id and descending  req_approvers.approved_at and specifying `nulls first` in a single CTE. Then update where the CTE where the date is not null. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9290fbd2284a581ca692d92a5698947b))

```
with approved(id, approved_at) as
     ( select distinct on (r.id)
              r.id 
            , ra.approved_at
         from reqs           r 
         join req_approvers  ra
           on ( ra.req_id = r.id
               and r.approved_at is null)
       order by r.id, ra.approved_at desc nulls first
     )
update reqs r  
   set approved_at = ap.approved_at
  from approved ap
 where r.id = ap.id 
   and ap.approved_at is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you Belayer. Ah I did think of doing something similar but using group by instead of distinct on. Obviously that won't work as you have to include all the columns you want to be projected (i.e. the req approvers approved_at column) in the group by clause and that is not what I want. I forgot about distinct on's similar behaviour.